# Use an application (like OneNote) as a background image

Tags: windows, images, windows-11, background, monitor-settings

I have a list of tasks I need to do. In order not to forget them, I would like to put them in a OneNote document. (Or whatever program: MS-Word, MS-Excel, Notepad++, ...)

Then, I would like to use this document as my Windows background, so every time I start up my PC or I minimise all windows, the first thing I see is my list of tasks to do.

Is this even possible? If yes, can somebody give me an idea on how to configure this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maximize your application, take a screen shot and use the image as the Windows background?

Comment: @DavidPostill: but what when I've finished a task, or if I want to add more? I would like the background to be dynamic, or "simulated dynamic", like when I double-click on the background image, the OneNote document appears and a simple action makes sure that the updated OneNote document gets maximised and used as the new background, something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Using a dynamic window as background is not possible.
I would recommend using instead a ToDo program that puts up a "sticker"
on your desktop.

One of the best is
[Stickies](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/stickies/index.html)
that creates a window (or multiple windows) that always below all other
windows, but that is not minimized when all the other windows are
minimized.

You may add or modify the text in the Stickies window, and the
modifications are carried through across reboots.

Comment: +1 for the quick and very useful response. I'm hoping not to accept your answer, because this would mean that my question is impossible :-)